Cloudflare Cache Purge Not Reflecting in Frontend but Works with Direct API Calls
I have an API that serves data to my frontend. The API is hosted behind Cloudflare, and so is Frontend. These are my API response headers cache-control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, public, s-maxage=604800 
When I make manual API requests by directly entering the API URL into the browser’s address bar (e.g., https://example.com/api/filter), I receive fresh data after purging the Cloudflare cache.
However, when the frontend makes the same API call, it receives a cached version of the data, even though the cache was just purged.
What I Have Tried:

After every data change (i.e., saving), I purge the cache using Cloudflare’s purge API. The purge seems successful since I can see fresh data when I call the API manually.
Request Headers in the Frontend: I have tried setting the following headers in the frontend requests to force fresh data:

Cache-Control: max-age=0

Example request headers when called from the frontend (React JS):
:authority: api.example.com
:method: GET
:path: /api/filters
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd
accept-language: en
cache-control: max-age=0
if-modified-since: Fri, 13 Sep 2024 09:44:21 GMT
origin: https://example.com
referer: https://example.com
sec-fetch-mode: cors
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/128.0.0.0 Safari/537.36

3 Cloudflare Response: After purging the cache, I still get a cf-cache-status: HIT in my frontend response headers, which indicates that the cached data is still being served:
cache-control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, public, s-maxage=604800
cf-cache-status: HIT
last-modified: Fri, 13 Sep 2024 09:29:46 GMT



Manual API Call Example:

When calling the API directly (e.g., typing the URL into the browser), I get fresh data, and the headers look something like this:
:authority: api.example.com
:method: GET
:path: /api/filters
:scheme: https
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*
cache-control: max-age=0
if-modified-since: Fri, 13 Sep 2024 09:44:21 GMT

What I Need Help With:

Why is the Cloudflare cache being purged correctly for manual API calls but not for frontend requests?
Is there anything specific I’m missing in terms of request headers or caching behavior?
How can I ensure that the frontend fetches fresh data after purging the Cloudflare cache?

NOTE: I have realized that when I purge everything from the API or manually from Cloudflare, it works perfectly fine. However, it does not work when I try to purge a specific URL.

I have found a workaround to purge the cache by URL. It suits my requirements, though it may not work for everyone. However, it might still help someone in the future.
To purge the cache from the front end, I have to pass the Origin in the headers along with the URL during the purge. Here's an example:
    "files": [{
      "url": "https://api.my-site.com/api/filters",
      "headers": {
        "Origin": "https://my-site.com"
      }
   }]

Make sure the "O" in Origin is uppercase.
NOTE: My API is on a separate domain, so I use api.my-site.com in the URL key. However, I want to clear the cache for my frontend site, so I use that domain in the Origin key. If you host both the API and frontend on the same domain, you can use the same hostname for both keys.
